# Is the press allowed to make initial contact with jurors after a trial?

Tags: united-states, jury

In the United States, jurors sometimes speak to the press after a trial, sometimes many years later. Does the press have a legal way to make initial contact with jurors directly, or indirectly such as through the court, or does the press just have to hope that jurors will come forward and speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been along-standing principle in the US that [names of jurors are publicly known](https://www.rcfp.org/journals/news-media-and-law-summer-2016/right-access-juror-names-an/), although there can be exceptions ([US v. Barnes](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-barnes-24), 604 F.2d 121 (1979) is the first case of a fully anonymous jury. Now, except in the 10th Circuit, they are allowed and not extremely rare (I don't know what the percentage is). So it would depend on whether the particular jury list is public.

Apart from the situation where a juror is harassed by the press and gets a court order to restrain approaches by a specific member of the press, if you can contact them, you can ask them questions. There cannot be a blanket "do not contact a juror" law / order in the US, which would be contrary to the 1st Amendment.